# ERB files not working in EasyPHP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, easyphp

I have installed EasyPHP 16.1 with Ruby and tested with Ruby files (.rb) and they are working. So Ruby is properly installed in EasyPHP. However the embedded ruby files (.erb) do not work in EasyPHP. For example out put of following erb file is something as given below.

Ruby File (.erb)

```
<h1>This is a test</h1>
<%= puts "Content-type: text/html"%>
<%= puts "Ruby example"%>
<% puts "#{10*5}"%>
%>
```

Result (as displayed in browser)

[Click here to see what gets displayed in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YLKn.jpg)

Comment: I am able to use the rails native server and run an application. I want to know if there is any way of running rails application on EasyPHP.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how it works.

Erb is a templating language and you'll need Ruby code to load the template, compile it and render it to the user. You cannot just server an .erb file and expect it to work.

Comment: actually I was just trying this. I created a rails application on EasyPHP server and generated a scaffold for a simple table and did db:migrate. It generated the required files and also created the tables. But when I navigate to the file from my browser again the result is directly printing the code from the file like its HTML text without any links.

Comment: I could run the puma server but I am still wondering if it can be run as a module on EasyPHP server